# Is it possible to determine an images width and height in liquid?

Tags: facebook, metadata, liquid, facebook-opengraph

I need to determine dynamic images width and height server side for facebook opengraph.  Is this possible using liquid?

Comment: Liquid cannot do this alone. I invite you to be more precise on your publishing plateform.

Comment: I built it on business catalyst, and I was able to solve it with a specific business catalyst method, but since BC is closing I have to transfer it and was hoping for a more universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to undestand if you need to define by yourself height and width or if you need to know width and height values. So let's answer both.

To define your image size:

```
{{ image | img_url: '500x600' }}
```

Here 500 is defining width of your image and 600 isvde defining its height.

To know width or height use the variable {{ image.height }} or {{ image.width }}

HTH

Comment: I need to know the exact width and height of the actual image so that facebook can appropriately load the image.  Without knowing the exact size it requires precaching which I am unable to do in this instance.

Comment: So the variables {{ image.width }} and {{ image.height }}   will give you these values.

Comment: Yeah I saw that in the shopfiy documentation.  I am using liquid on Business Catalyst and for some reason that doesn't work.  It returns a null value.